# How to render pixels from IMFMediaBuffer or IMF2DBuffer into HWND?

Tags: c++, video, direct3d, ms-media-foundation, direct2d

I'm trying to better understand [Microsoft media foundation framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/microsoft-media-foundation-sdk). Say, if I have a win32 window in my app (or its HWND handle), how do I render pixels from the `IMF2DBuffer` (or at least from `IMFMediaBuffer`) into it?

PS. Do I need to use the good old GDI: device contexts, `CreateDIBSection`/`GetDIBits` and `BitBlt`/`StretchBlt`?

Comment: It depends on your context. Using GDI is always possible if you have access to the bytes/pixels, but you should instead use DirectX , DXGI, create a swap chain on the HWND (for example https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dxgi1_2/nf-dxgi1_2-idxgifactory2-createswapchainforhwnd) and use IMFDXGIDeviceManager (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/mfobjects/nn-mfobjects-imfdxgidevicemanager). You could also install a D2D device on all this (D2D depends on DXGI+D3D)

Comment: @SimonMourier Thanks, I'm just starting out with D2D. But I'll try your suggestion.

Comment: Found this [code sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation/MFCaptureD3D). I'm not sure if this is it.

Comment: This one's using DirectX9 which is kinda old too :-) but you get the idea

Comment: @SimonMourier: I'll probably need a bit more of your help. So I managed to init & create DirectX 11 objects for the HWND. But now I'm stuck. How do I render video data that I get in `IMF2DBuffer` or `IMFMediaBuffer` using `IDXGISwapChain`, and `ID3D11RenderTargetView`?

Comment: Is this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77066463/resource-manipulation-error-281-when-calling-id3d11devicecontextcopysubresour related?

Comment: @SimonMourier yes, I posted my code to explain what I'm doing. Do you have any idea what I'm doing wrong there?

Answer (score 1):

You can use GDI too, but this is just way out of date.

In most cases, when you are to create modern, performant, power efficient application, you would expect at least some amount of hardware acceleration. Quite so often your video comes from encoded stream, and your `IMFMediaBuffer` comes from video decoder with video frame backed by DirectX texture in video memory. You want to render it without accessing its actual bits. In other cases you use Direct3D to produce content, or you use another video API (such as Direct2D) with interop into Direct3D.

The common ground here is that your content is already in video memory, and you want to render into Direct3D swapchain to visualize. Quite so often this has simple Direct3D scene involved, and you render this video frame as a resource into it.

You would normally prefer Direct3D11 to Direct3D9 because the latter is already out of date too, even though Media Foundation is also a bit rusty (specifically, public well known MF samples use rather Direct3D9).

But you of course you can cut corners and flush image into good old DIB and present with GDI.

Comment: Roman, I appreciate the theory. Unfortunately I'm quite new to Direct*** programming. An actual code sample of how to do it would be of great help.

Comment: I would have shared if I had or even know something suitable. Sadly I am not aware of much, pieces of related information are scattered.

Comment: I am stuck on this part: do you know how to render `IMFMediaBuffer` in a `IDXGISwapChain`? I can get `IMFDXGIBuffer` out of `IMFMediaBuffer` via QueryInterface, then `ID3D11Texture2D` out of `IMFDXGIBuffer` via QueryInterface as well. But then I'm stuck. I don't know DX well enough to know what to do next. Any pointers?