# RESOURCE_MANIPULATION ERROR #281 when calling ID3D11DeviceContext::CopySubresourceRegion to render video from a webcam

Tags: c++, directx, ms-media-foundation, direct3d11, dxgi

I'm trying to re-write my software-only logic for displaying video feed from a web camera. This time using hardware and DirectX. (I need to preface this by saying that this is the first time that I'm writing something for DirectX.)

I have the following declared on the global scale:

```
IMFMediaSource* g_pMediaSource = NULL;
ReaderCallback* gpRdrCallback = NULL;
IMFSourceReader* g_pSrcReader = NULL;

//DirectX stuff:
IDXGISwapChain1* g_pHW_SwapChain = NULL;               
ID3D11Device1* g_pHW_D3DDevice = NULL;                 
ID3D11DeviceContext1* g_pHW_ImmContext = NULL;         
IMFDXGIDeviceManager* g_pHW_DXGIDevMgr = NULL;         
ID3D11RenderTargetView* g_pHW_RenderTargetView = NULL; 
ID3D11Texture2D* g_pHW_BackBuffer = NULL;
```

I get the `IMFMediaSource` for the webcam, using this code when the app starts:

```
//Error handling is omitted for readability
CComPtr<IMFAttributes> com_attributes;
hr = MFCreateAttributes(&com_attributes, 2);

hr = com_attributes->SetGUID(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE,
                             MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_GUID);

hr = com_attributes->SetString(MF_DEVSOURCE_ATTRIBUTE_SOURCE_TYPE_VIDCAP_SYMBOLIC_LINK, 
                               strWebcamSymLink.c_str());

CComPtr<IMFActivate> com_Activ;
hr = MFCreateDeviceSourceActivate(com_attributes, &com_Activ);

hr = com_Activ->ActivateObject(IID_PPV_ARGS(&g_pMediaSource));
```

Then I do the following (once) during initialization to set up DirectX:

(Error handling is omitted for readability.)

```
//For this test, the input parameters are:
//(As they are received from a webcam)
//
//  szFrameW = 160;
//  szFrameH = 90;
//  nFrameRateNumer = 5;
//  nFrameRateDenom = 1;
//  nAspectRatioNumer = 1;
//  nAspectRatioDenom = 1;
//  dwIdxDev = 0;            //Webcam device index
//

DXGI_SWAP_CHAIN_DESC sd = {};

sd.BufferCount = 1;

sd.BufferDesc.Width = szFrameW;
sd.BufferDesc.Height = szFrameH;
sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
sd.BufferDesc.ScanlineOrdering = DXGI_MODE_SCANLINE_ORDER_PROGRESSIVE;
sd.BufferDesc.Scaling = DXGI_MODE_SCALING_CENTERED;
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Numerator = nFrameRateNumer;
sd.BufferDesc.RefreshRate.Denominator = nFrameRateDenom;

sd.BufferUsage = DXGI_USAGE_RENDER_TARGET_OUTPUT;

sd.OutputWindow = ghWnd;       //Main window handle
sd.Windowed = TRUE;

sd.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
sd.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;


D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL d3dFeatureLvls[] = {
    D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL_11_1,
};

UINT dwNumLvlsRequested = _countof(d3dFeatureLvls);

D3D_FEATURE_LEVEL FeatureLevelsSupported;

CComPtr<IDXGISwapChain> com_SwapChain;
CComPtr<ID3D11Device> com_Dev;
CComPtr<ID3D11DeviceContext> com_Ctx;

hr = D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain(NULL, 
    D3D_DRIVER_TYPE_HARDWARE, 
    NULL, 
    D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_BGRA_SUPPORT |
#ifdef _DEBUG
    D3D11_CREATE_DEVICE_DEBUG
#else
    0
#endif
    ,
    d3dFeatureLvls, 
    dwNumLvlsRequested, 
    D3D11_SDK_VERSION, 
    &sd, 
    &com_SwapChain, 
    &com_Dev, 
    &FeatureLevelsSupported,
    &com_Ctx);

//Get version 1.0 of interfaces - I'm not sure if I need it here?
hr = com_SwapChain.QueryInterface(&g_pHW_SwapChain);
hr = com_Dev.QueryInterface(&g_pHW_D3DDevice);
hr = com_Ctx.QueryInterface(&g_pHW_ImmContext);

hr = g_pHW_SwapChain->GetBuffer(0, IID_PPV_ARGS(&g_pHW_BackBuffer));

hr = g_pHW_D3DDevice->CreateRenderTargetView(g_pHW_BackBuffer, NULL, &g_pHW_RenderTargetView);

g_pHW_ImmContext->OMSetRenderTargets(1, &g_pHW_RenderTargetView, NULL);

D3D11_VIEWPORT vp;
vp.Width = (FLOAT)szFrameW;
vp.Height = (FLOAT)szFrameH;
vp.MinDepth = 0.0f;
vp.MaxDepth = 1.0f;
vp.TopLeftX = 0;
vp.TopLeftY = 0;

g_pHW_ImmContext->RSSetViewports( 1, &vp );

CComPtr<IMFTransform> com_Transform;
hr = g_pMediaSource->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&com_Transform));

UINT uiToken = 0;
hr = MFCreateDXGIDeviceManager(&uiToken, &g_pHW_DXGIDevMgr);

hr = g_pHW_DXGIDevMgr->ResetDevice(g_pHW_D3DDevice, uiToken);

hr = com_Transform->ProcessMessage(MFT_MESSAGE_SET_D3D_MANAGER, 
                                   (ULONG_PTR)g_pHW_DXGIDevMgr);
```

Then to initiate the Microsoft Media Foundation for asynchronous rendering from a webcam:

```
//Error handling is omitted for readability

hr = MFCreateAttributes(&com_attributes, 3);

gpRdrCallback = new ReaderCallback();
hr = com_attributes->SetUnknown(MF_SOURCE_READER_ASYNC_CALLBACK, gpRdrCallback);

hr = com_attributes->SetUINT32(MF_SOURCE_READER_ENABLE_ADVANCED_VIDEO_PROCESSING, TRUE);
hr = com_attributes->SetUINT32(MF_SOURCE_READER_DISCONNECT_MEDIASOURCE_ON_SHUTDOWN, TRUE);
hr = com_attributes->SetUnknown(MF_SOURCE_READER_D3D_MANAGER, g_pHW_DXGIDevMgr);

hr = MFCreateSourceReaderFromMediaSource(g_pMediaSource, com_attributes, &g_pSrcReader);

CComPtr<IMFMediaType> com_vid_output;
hr = MFCreateMediaType(&com_vid_output);

hr = com_vid_output->SetGUID(MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video);
hr = com_vid_output->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32);
hr = com_vid_output->SetUINT32(MF_MT_INTERLACE_MODE, MFVideoInterlace_Progressive);
hr = com_vid_output->SetUINT64(MF_MT_FRAME_SIZE, 
                               PackSize(szFrameW, szFrameH));

hr = com_vid_output->SetUINT64(MF_MT_FRAME_RATE, 
                               PackSize(nFrameRateNumer, nFrameRateDenom));

hr = MFSetAttributeRatio(com_vid_output,
    MF_MT_PIXEL_ASPECT_RATIO,
    nAspectRatioNumer,
    nAspectRatioDenom);

hr = g_pSrcReader->SetCurrentMediaType(dwIdxDev, NULL, com_vid_output);

//Initiate the read from a webcam (async)
hr = g_pSrcReader->SetStreamSelection(dwIdxDev, TRUE);
hr = g_pSrcReader->ReadSample(dwIdxDev,
                              0,
                              NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
```

After that from my `ReaderCallback` when a frame is read:

```
//Error handling is omitted for readability

HRESULT ReaderCallback::OnReadSample(HRESULT hrStatus, 
                                     DWORD dwStreamIndex,
                                     DWORD dwStreamFlags,
                                     LONGLONG llTimestamp,
                                     IMFSample* pSample)
{
    if(SUCCEEDED(hrStatus))
    {
        CComPtr<IMFMediaBuffer> com_buffer;
        hr = pSample->ConvertToContiguousBuffer(&com_buffer);

        com_buffer->AddRef();   /pseudo-call
        remember_video_buffer_for_later_processing(com_buffer);
        
    }

    //Initiate reading of another frame
    hr = g_pSrcReader->ReadSample(dwIdxDev,
                              0,
                              NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

    return S_OK;
}
```

Finally, when I am ready to render the video frame onto the window:
(The frame is received from my `ReaderCallback::OnReadSample` above.)

```
//Error handling is omitted for readability

void renderFromRawVideoPixels(IMFMediaBuffer* pMediaBuffer)
{
    CComPtr<IMFDXGIBuffer> com_DxgBuffer;
    hr = pMediaBuffer->QueryInterface(IID_PPV_ARGS(&com_DxgBuffer));

    CComPtr<ID3D11Texture2D> com_Texture;
    hr = com_DxgBuffer->GetResource(IID_PPV_ARGS(&com_Texture));

    UINT nSubindex;
    hr = com_DxgBuffer->GetSubresourceIndex(&nSubindex);

    g_pHW_ImmContext->CopySubresourceRegion(g_pHW_BackBuffer,
        0, 0 ,0, 0,
        com_Texture,
        nSubindex,
        NULL);

    DXGI_PRESENT_PARAMETERS dpp = {};
    hr = g_pHW_SwapChain->Present1(0, 0, &dpp);
}
```

The call to `g_pHW_ImmContext->CopySubresourceRegion` above leaves the following error in the debugging output window and I get a black screen:

> D3D11 ERROR: ID3D11DeviceContext::CopySubresourceRegion: Cannot invoke
> CopySubresourceRegion when the Formats of each Resource are not the
> same or at least castable to each other, unless one format is
> compressed (DXGI_FORMAT_R9G9B9E5_SHAREDEXP, or
> DXGI_FORMAT_BC[1,2,3,4,5,6,7]_* ) and the source format is similar to
> the dest according to: BC[1|4] ~= R16G16B16A16|R32G32, BC[2|3|5|6|7]
> ~= R32G32B32A32, R9G9B9E5_SHAREDEXP ~= R32. [ RESOURCE_MANIPULATION
> ERROR #281: COPYSUBRESOURCEREGION_INVALIDSOURCE]

I have no idea what it means.

Any help on how to resolve this?

Comment: I would say if you call `GetDesc` of those resources behind `g_pHW_BackBuffer` and `com_Texture` before the `CopySubresourceRegion` call, you would be able to see how exactly they are incompatible for the copy operation.

Comment: @RomanR. and if they are incompatible, what is the way to convert them from one to another?

Comment: Here's the difference. The `com_Texture`: `{format=DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM; BindFlags=D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET | D3D11_BIND_SHADER_RESOURCE}`, while `g_pHW_BackBuffer`: `{format=DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM; BindFlags=D3D11_BIND_RENDER_TARGET;}`

Comment: The two resources are both 32 bpp, but still the formats are different B8G8R8X8_UNORM vs R8G8B8A8_UNORM. You definitely don't want to copy BGR to RGB in any case. You want to have compatible format there, probably the easiest is to create swapchain with the format which is going to be compatible.

Comment: @RomanR. I just tried it. First off, when I specify `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM` to my call to `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain` it returns `E_INVALIDARG`. But even if that succeeded, where do I get the format to feed into `D3D11CreateDeviceAndSwapChain`? Isn't it dependent on a webcam.

Comment: If you don't need the frames themselves, or just need them for rendering on the screen there are usually built-in ways, (for example IMFCaptureEngine, or using WinRT and UWP or WinUI3 MediaPlayerElement (like shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/76964419/403671). Otherwise, do you have some full reproducing code somewhere?

Comment: @SimonMourier thanks. I'll spend some time creating a POC project if I get stuck. For now, let me try to figure it out myself. Can you guide me though. I did some research and it seems like I may need VideoProcessor to convert from one format to another. Am I correct? If so, do you know any code sample how to do it? (Basically steps in my `renderFromRawVideoPixels`)

Comment: Depends on your code. MF's DSP are here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/medfound/windowsmediadigitalsignalprocessors you may want to use Color Converter DSP (for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15341038/imftransform-interface-of-color-converter-dsp-giving-e-invalidarg-on-setinputtyp), but as Roman said, if the problem is RGB vs BGR, it probably means you're on the wrong path :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the system tells you, the formats between what Media Foundation gives you back and what the DirectX swapchain expects are not compatible.

You can make them compatible with two changes:

A) change the swapchain format, change this:

```
sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_R8G8B8A8_UNORM;
```

into this:

```
sd.BufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM;
```

B) change MF output video format, change this:

```
hr = com_vid_output->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_RGB32);
=> MF will give you back DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM
```

into this:

```
hr = com_vid_output->SetGUID(MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_ARGB32);
=> MF will give you back DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM
```

Comment: Thanks. But oh wow, seriously. That's what was wrong with it ‍♂️ I did try to change the format but chose `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8X8_UNORM` instead of `DXGI_FORMAT_B8G8R8A8_UNORM`.

Comment: A follow-up if you don't mind. Why is it stretching it to the size of the entire window though? Didn't I specify the `D3D11_VIEWPORT` to be the size of the frame?

Comment: It's not only the swapchain format, it's essentially the MF output format. Follow up: not sure if you can do that with a windowed swapchain created like that. You can instead create it using CreateSwapChainForHwnd (and create device with D3D11CreateDevice), like in here https://pastebin.com/raw/3a2Gg8v3 PS: your render target view is useless here (you just want a DXGI surface basically), CreateRenderTargetView OMSetRenderTargets and RSSetViewports can be removed.